# PhpStorm 2022.2.3 CLI spam of processes

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

When PhpStorm starts, it starts to endlessly create CLI (php icon) processes that do not close, each of which weighs about 6 megabytes. This leads to a complete depletion of RAM after a few minutes.

What could this be related to?

At startup, no project opens by default — only a dialog box with recent projects opens.

[image]

Comment: 1) So this happens when no project is opened, only the Welcome screen? 2) Please disable all custom (not bundled by default) plugins -- `/downloaded` and restart the IDE. Any difference? 3) Does it happen when you have no other apps opened (especially browsers)?

Comment: If you have an open project then I could think that it might be caused by some PHP_CodeSniffer integration or another Code Quality Tool .. but when nothing is opened...

Comment: Hi, first of all I want to thank you for your time, but I already solved the problem.
Second of all, the problem was in my alias terminal command, which I had on my system. It was not working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's decided. It was in my Windows terminal. I made a mistake in the alias syntax, which led to an endless restart of the CLI wherever it was used.